# Vue | leave class not getting removed

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a vue component which is animated using vue animations

the only problem I'm facing is that the element keeps the leave class for longer than specified in the name-leave-active class.

to be more specific it keeps the leave-active and leave-to classes longer than it should.

```js
<script setup>
const show = ref(false);
const toggleShow = () => {
  show.value = !show.value;
  console.log(show.value);
};
</script>
<template>
  <div
    @click="toggleShow"
    class="mx-20 p-4 aurora-inner rounded-t-lg flex justify-between"
  >
    <div>something</div>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 448 512"
      :class="{ svg: show }"
    >
      <!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. -->
      <path
        d="M224 416c-8.188 0-16.38-3.125-22.62-9.375l-192-192c-12.5-12.5-12.5-32.75 0-45.25s32.75-12.5 45.25 0L224 338.8l169.4-169.4c12.5-12.5 32.75-12.5 45.25 0s12.5 32.75 0 45.25l-192 192C240.4 412.9 232.2 416 224 416z"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <transition name="acc">
    <div
      v-show="show"
      class="aurora-inner mx-20 p-4 pt-2 border-t border-blue-400"
    >
      smth else
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<style scoped>
svg {
  filter: invert(47%) sepia(9%) saturate(564%) hue-rotate(182deg)
    brightness(90%) contrast(88%);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.acc-enter-from,
.acc-leave-to {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.acc-enter-active,
.acc-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you leave, the transition will take 1s because it's one way and then the way back no? Or is it some other delay?

Comment: when the transition is done, and the element is at leave-to there's like a 1s delay where it stays at this position and then updates.

Comment: Not sure what is not working on your side but I've tried your code, checked the exact duration of it into the `Animations` tab of Chrome and it is exactly .4s with not additional delay. Your issue is coming from somewhere else. A [repro] would be highly helpful to debug it further IMO.